# detecting if video source is set in html5 video player

Tags: javascript, html, video

In my application I need to make sure that a user has set a video as source of my html5 video player, before continuing with the other actions. So I tried this (using Firebug in Firefox):

When user has set a source for the videoplayer

```
vp = $('#myvideoplayer')
vp.attr('src')  --> "blob:5c254454-6c4e-4b69-b381-9ad60d6b1c4a"
```

when no source is set for the video

```
vp.attr('src')  --> undefined
```

Can I use this to detect if a user has set the video source or not?

```
if(vp.attr('src') != undefined){
   let_user_do_next_action();
}
```

Or is there any better way?

p.s:

I am setting the source of video using an HTML5 file input widget as follows. (This works only in Firefox, since Chrome doesn't allow `createObjectURL` from `window.webkitURL` for some reason.)

```
var file = $('#fileselect').get(0).files[0];
if (file==undefined){
    alert('no file chosen');
}
var myURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var fileURL = myURL.createObjectURL(file);
if(fileURL){
    player = $('#myvideoplayer');
    player.src=fileURL;
    player.load();
}
return;
```

Comment: `Can I use this to detect if a user has set the video source or not?` What happens when you try this? Are you seeing evidence that it doesn't work? If so, any errors? If so, please post them. Good luck! :)

Comment: @ jmort253, I tried that and it was working ,but was afraid that it was a bit convoluted.thanks for the comment

Comment: Makes sense.  Simple is better, so if there is a simpler solution that's the one to go with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should work, or if you want to be foolproof, check `typeof vp.attr('src') == "undefined"`.Though if you don't use jQuery you might want to check `element.hasAttribute("src")` instead.

About `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL`, I think Chrome restricts stuff when you're testing it locally (e.g. on a `file://` URL), and you'd either have to set up a simple HTTP server on localhost, or [start Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) with `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Comment: thanks for the reply..and that nugget about starting chrome with flags was extra bonus!much obliged!